# C++ program to calculate the sum of all five-digit odd numbers?

Tags: c++, sum

I'm having a problem with the following simple code, I don't know why the output will become negative... The program is supposed to calculate the sum of all odd and five-digit numbers like 10001, 10003, 10005, etc.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, sum = 0;

    for (num = 10001 ; num <= 99999 ; num+=2){
        sum += num;
    }

    cout << num << " " << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just in case you aren't aware of how large a number you will need to hold eventually - your final result will be 9.2x10^9

Comment: @Kvothe: you are wrong: `np.sum(np.arange(10**4 + 1, 10**5, 2))` yields 2475000000. @Sepehr Student: you don't need an algorithm to do that, you can use the gaus trick and get: `(10**4 + 1 + 10**5 - 1) * (10**5 - 10**4) / 4 = 10**(2 * (5 - 1)) * 99 / 4 = 2475000000`

Comment: @RuggeroTurra I used the trick "sum of odd integers from 1 to N where N is even is `(N^2)/4`" but forget the division by 4, so it should be `((10^5)^2 - (10^4)^2)/4 = 2.3 * 10^9`. I don't understand how your method works, can you provide a link to anywhere so I can look at it properly?

Comment: @Kvothe: it is exactly the same trick. In fact your formula is identical to mine. Please do not round the result since the question is about integer sum.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are completely correct. I just spotted my mistake, couldn't read my own handwriting... I'll stop doing maths for tonight now...

Answer (score 2):

Your `int` will likely overflow. Switch it to `long`

```
int num = 0;
long long sum = 0L;
```

Assuming you have a 4 byte `int`, the maximum value will be `2^31 - 1 == 2147483647`. [See this example](http://cpp.sh/9jrf)

Your sum will come out to `2475000000` which will overflow.

Comment: Long is only guaranteed to represent values from -2147483647 to 2147483647. In this case it would overflow anyway.

Comment: @Phantom Good catch, threw on another `long` for good measure :)

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is an overflow of type int. That is this type can not represent the sum. I advice to declare variable sum like

```
long long int sum = 0;
```

After that you can compare the result with the maximum value stored in type int. For example

```
#include <limits>

//...

std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << " " << sum << std::endl;;
```